# JavaScript квадратный корень из большого (BigInt ) целого числа

Tags: javascript

Что можно использовать в JS для вычисления квадратного корня из целого числа типа BigInt?
Обычный Math.sqrt() не работает с числами типа BigInt.

Comment: https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/09/javascript-bigint.html

Comment: static rootNth(value, k = 2n)  - этот метод глючит при размере числа более 55 знаков. Я его уже видел. НЕ ГОДИТСЯ.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigint-isqrt подойдёт?

Comment: Спасибо. Работает :-)

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570700/SquareplusRootplusalgorithmplusforplusC - наверно оттуда тоже можно что-то вытянуть)

Comment: [JavaScript big integer square root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683995/javascript-big-integer-square-root).

Comment: НЕ ГОДИТСЯ — а вы в код смотрели? Там кодличество итераций ограничено 100. Выставить побольше и будет годиться для 55 знаков

Comment: Уже ничего "выставлять побольше" не надо. Решение найдено безо всяких выставлений. Спасибо за наезд :-)

Comment: Для Stanislav Volodarskiy
Этот пример тоже НЕ ГОДИТСЯ. Там переполнение стека из-за рекурсии происходит менее чем при 7000 знаков.

Answer (score 0):

Для полноты картины, пока ждал ответ наваял вот такое своё.

```
function BigSqrt(n){
  var n1,n2,nc,nkv;
  if (n < 0n) throw 'Square root of negative numbers is not supported';
  n1=0n;n2=n;
  while(n2*n2>n) n2=n2/1000n;
  n2=n2*1000n;
  nc=(n1+n2)/2n;
  while(true) {
     nkv=nc*nc;
     if(nkv == n) return nc;
     if(nkv>n) n2=nc; else n1=nc;  
     if((n2-n1) <= 1) break;
     nc=(n2+n1)/2n;
  }
  while(nc*nc < n) nc++;
  while(nc*nc > n) nc--;
  
  return nc;
}
```